# How to reset children's component state in react

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Here are my components for the app:

```
<SystemList />
<SystemDetail />
  <WorldList />
  <WorldDetail />
```

The data structure is that there are several systems, each system has several worlds. Each world has the detailed information.

In the react, when click each system, it has an action to get the activeSystem, then SystemDetail would render the information. Inside of the SystemDetail, it has two children component called WorldList and WorldDetail. When click the world list, there is an action to display the world detail information.

So my app works fine after click system list, it gets to the system detail, then after clicking the world list, it gets to the world detail. However, I had an problem to reset the world detail, which means when I click the system list again, the world detail still shows up the previous world.

I tried to set the key for the component, but it did not work. I also tried to pass the props, or reset the props, it did not work either.

How can I reset the state for the WorldDetail component after clicking the System in the SystemList? Does it make sense? Or maybe the mockup would make more sense.[image]

I am quite new to react and redux, so any help would be great!

Comment: So I ended up with using localStorage.setItem('clickedPlanet', true); to set the "clickedPlanet" flag to see if user clicked the System list, then check this value to print out world detail.

Comment: Doesn't your "world detail component" just need to be responsible for its own state...

Answer (score 6):

You can use `componentWillReceiveProps` inside `WorldDetail` to change this state. When it receive new props from `SystemDetail`.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried, but it did not work. SystemDetail get the new props, but it requires an action to change its state. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Lisa React should rerender component if you call `setState` in `componentWillReceiveProps`. Do you call `setState`? Also, could you share some of your code with us, it will make it much easier to help you.

Comment: Yes, I called the setState, but it still did not work. I ended up with setting up a flag in the localStorage to detect if use clicked the system list. Thanks all the same!

Comment: @Lisa If you still wanna use componentWillReceiveProps. You can use parent State value in child props. It will work hopefully.